# Translating EnumDropDownListFor containing DayOfWeek

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, dayofweek

I need to translate my MVC website in different languages. I cannot translate the enumdropdownlist containing a DayOfWeek property.

This is how I show the combobox in the View:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Day, "Select Day", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

There is an easy way to have it globalized. (Using resources or something else)

Comment: The best option is going to be to create your own DayOfWeek enum and add the correct Display attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the day is coming from DB or it is default.  If it is default then it will automatically work, once you put below line as per your language need.

```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
```

Please go through below example
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati

Comment: I just did the globalization. I just only need to change the language of that part. For other parts I did it through resources. For model I did it using "ResourceType". I did not find the way to translate directly the DayofWeek in that dropdownlist

Comment: From where you are getting the days value.... I mean where you are stored those values.

Comment: I use the standard values